# Can you tell if a parameter passed to a function is an anonymous temporary at the calling site?

Tags: c++

I have a case where it would be useful to be able to tell if a function parameter is an anonymous temporary in the caller.

Is there a way to do this with C++ traits?

Assume any C++ standard is available to me.

Comment: *"I have a case where it would be useful to be able to tell if a function parameter is an anonymous temporary in the caller."* -- doubtful. You might have something close, but probably not exactly.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you are asking, but what about `f(T&)`   + `f(const T&)` overloads.

Comment: Or especially f(T&&) overload.

Comment: If what you actually want to do is not accept temporary values then taking your parameter by non-const reference will do that

Comment: why would it be useful? DOes `std::move(x)` count as "unnamed temporary" ?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for [member functions with ref-qualifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions)?